# How to make sure that if week does not contain 1st Jan it would be Week53 in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wish to generate the week number of the date based on few scenarios. 
1) Week that contain 1st Jan must be Week1, like 2015-12-31, since it is lay into the same week as 1st Jan, it will be WEEK1.
2) If that week does not contain 1st Jan, like 2016-12-31, it will be WEEK53.

```
declare @dt date
set @dt='2015/12/31';
SELECT  @dt
    , CASE  WHEN DATEPART(wk, @dt) <> 53 
            THEN DATEPART(wk, @dt) 
            ELSE 1 
      END
```

The code above will help me fulfill the scenario one but not scenario 2. As whhen it comes to 2016-12-31, that week will become WEEK1 instead of WEEK53. Please help.

Comment: Which dbms is this? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL... Using product specific functions.)

Comment: BTW, why having your own week numbering, different from everybodys else?

Comment: It is a part of the requirement of my project :)

Comment: But you still don't know the required dbms?

Comment: Im not sure what you want. But I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @dt date
set @dt='2015/12/31';

SELECT @dt, CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt) < 53 
            THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)

            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 7 
            THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 6 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (8-datepart(weekday, @dt))%7, @dt))=1
            THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 5 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (8-datepart(weekday, @dt))%7, @dt))<=2
            THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 4 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (8-datepart(weekday, @dt))%7, @dt))<=3
            THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 3 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (8-datepart(weekday, @dt))%7, @dt))<=4
            THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 2 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (8-datepart(weekday, @dt))%7, @dt))<=5
            THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 1 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (8-datepart(weekday, @dt))%7, @dt))<=6
            THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)         
            ELSE
            1
        END
```

Comment: You can check which day of the week is set as the 'first day' with below query;
select @@DATEFIRST
If this is 7, than it is SUNDAY, if it is 1, it is MONDAY.

Comment: By the way, can i know why you got this idea to do this? To be honest I never have this in my mind. You save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

I modify the answer a bit as the above answer does not fulfill the requirement for year 2018/12/30. The code below can fulfill for year 2015 to 2021. :)

```
declare @dt date
set @dt='2015/12/27';

SELECT @dt, CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt) < 53 
        THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)

        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 7 
        THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 6 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (9-datepart(weekday, @dt))%9, @dt))=1
        THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 5 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (9-datepart(weekday, @dt))%9, @dt))<=2
        THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 4 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (9-datepart(weekday, @dt))%9, @dt))<=3
        THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 3 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (9-datepart(weekday, @dt))%9, @dt))<=4
        THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 2 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (9-datepart(weekday, @dt))%9, @dt))<=5
        THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)
        WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@dt) = 1 AND DATEDIFF(D,@dt,DATEADD(day, (9-datepart(weekday, @dt))%9, @dt))<=6
        THEN DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)         
        ELSE
        1
    END
```